# Dynamic align text to the center

Tags: c++, qt

How i could stop the `Loading` text from moving to the left, but still continue aligned to the center of the button?

[image: 2022-12-12_18-57-56.gif]

```
auto timer = new QTimer();
auto button = new QPushButton(this);

button->setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 50);
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
button->setLayout(layout);

QLabel* label = new QLabel(button);
label->setStyleSheet("qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;");

layout->addWidget(label);

timer->setInterval(500);
timer->start();

QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]
{
    static int dot = 0;

    dot = (dot + 1) % 4;

    QString text = "Loading...";
    text.resize(7 + dot);

    label->setText(text);
});
```

Comment: Many ways... As a quick and dirty solution, I'd consider adding dots on both sides of the text, and using rich text just make the dots on left side be same color as background.

Comment: You can calculate the center position of the text for "Loading..." and always use that position regardless of what's displayed. You could also split it into two lines with Loading on top and the periods on the bottom.

Comment: Another way would be to subclass `QWidget` to create `LabelWrapper`, which would contain two `QLabel` widgets, one for the fixed "Loading" text and another for the dots, and use suitably set up `QGridLayout` to position them so that `Loading` text is in the middle and dots do not move it. (Anybody feel free to write an example implementation).